# How to get all inventory groups variables in hierarchy via Python API?

Tags: python, automation, ansible, devops

I want to collect all inventory hosts groups variables in hierarchy data struct and send them to Consul to make them available in runtime.

Calling this method - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/inventory/manager.py#L160 I got the error

```
inventory.get_vars()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    inventory.get_vars()
  File "<>/.virtualenvs/ansible27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 160, in get_vars
    return self._inventory.get_vars(args, kwargs)
AttributeError: 'InventoryData' object has no attribute 'get_vars'
```

my script

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint

from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager

loader = DataLoader()
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='inventories/itops-vms.yml')
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

# shows groups as well
pp(inventory.groups)

# shows dict as well with content
pp(variable_manager.get_vars())

# creates an unhandled exception
inventory.get_vars()
```

How to do that right way?

- Python 2.7.15
- ansible==2.6.2
- OS Mac High Siera

Comment: Did you try the `list_groups` method? You can check out all the available methods here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8aea8901c353a18b3a58156eb1d5cb7e24825af0/lib/ansible/inventory/manager.py

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*all inventory hosts groups variables*". What if variables in different groups had different values? What if hosts had variables defined?

Comment: I want to get something similar to `$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/itops-vms.yml --graph --vars` result in python in some data struct which I could walk/read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself seems to be caused by a bug - the `get_vars` method of the inventory object calls `get_vars` method of the [`InventoryData`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/71eabf134fdbac28594e881515d7ed76c76f270e/lib/ansible/inventory/data.py) object which is not implemented.

---

You need to specify the group, for example:

```
>>> inventory.groups['all'].get_vars()
{u'my_var': u'value'}
```

You can create a dictionary with that data:

```
{g: inventory.groups[g].get_vars() for g in inventory.groups}
```

---

<sup>The above gets only the variables defined in the inventory itself (which is what the question asks about). If you wanted to get a structure with variables from group_vars, host_vars, etc. (as you indicated in your comment [*I want to get something similar to `$ ansible-inventory -i inventories/itops-vms.yml --graph --vars`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791774/how-to-get-all-inventory-groups-variables-in-hierarchy-via-python-api#comment90545512_51791774) you'd need to collect the data from different sources, just like Ansible does.</sup>